# Converting apache rewrite rules (.htaccess) to nginx

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

**Background:**

I want to setup [Bugify](https://bugify.com/) on my Ubuntu Server running nginx. I followed the instructions, installed the dependencies and the installation was successful. Once I enter my licence key and click on "Install Bugify" it's redirecting to http://dev.mysite.com/login?new and the only thing I'm seeing is `404 Not Found`.

I know that nginx isn't officially supported but according to the [support forum](http://support.bugify.com/kb/installing-and-updating/can-i-use-nginx) it should be possible to run it.

**Question:**

There's a `.htaccess` file with rewrite rules in the webapp's public directory and I guess the problem causing the 404 error is that nginx isn't able to work with the `.htaccess` file, so I'll have to convert the rewrite rules to the nginx syntax.

I'm not really familiar with apache's rewrite rules so I'd need some help figuring this out.

The content of the .htaccess file is:

```
# Rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I was using [this tool](http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/) to convert the rules but it's having some troubles with the `-` flags.

```
#ignored: "-" thing used or unknown variable in regex/rew
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The dashes the converter is "ignoring" are the ones that mean don't rewrite the matching request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugify uses the Zend Framework, so the rewrite rules for ZF should work for Bugify also.  I have copied the suggested nginx config below from http://wiki.nginx.org/Zend_Framework

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root /var/www/www.example.com/myapplication;
  index  index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass      unix:/usr/local/zend/tmp/php-fastcgi.socket;
    fastcgi_index    index.php;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/www.example.com/myapplication$fastcgi_script_name;
    include               fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using the exact same nginx config except without the

`try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;`

part. I added it and everything's working now. Thanks for the support even if nginx isn't officially supported. I guess you could add it to the supported webserver list if you add this snippet to the bugify knowledge base!